# Symfony - Error when saving OneToOne relationship via form

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm getting the following error when trying to save a submitted form which includes a unidirectional OneToOne relationship:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO person
>   (first_name, last_name, title, gender, phone1, phone2, mobile, fax,
>   email, birth, add_info, address_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?)' with params ["sdf", "sdf", null, "m", null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, null, 12, "employee"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR: could not determine
>   data type of parameter $13

**Edit**: the value "employee" is not inserted by filling in the form. I don't know where it comes from.

The ID of address seems correctly auto generated and increases each time I try to save the form.

This is my Code:

Person:

```
/**
 * Person Model - used as parent for Employee and ContactPerson and instance in Customer
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KuMiV\StoreBundle\Entity\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person 
{
  ... (all the other attributes)
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adress_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
   protected $address;
   ... (getter and setter)
}
```

Employee:

namespace KuMiV\EmployeeBundle\Entity;

use KuMiV\StoreBundle\Entity\Person;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

```
/**
 * Employee Model - extends from Person
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "KuMiV\StoreBundle\Entity\Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="employee")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KuMiV\EmployeeBundle\Entity\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee extends Person 
{   ...
   /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
   * @Assert\Type(type="string")
   */
    private $svn 
    ... (getter and setter)
}
```

AddressForm:

```
class AddressForm extends AbstractType 
{
    // set the data class of the form
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'KuMiV\StoreBundle\Entity\Address',
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder       
            ->add('street', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Straße*'))
            ->add('number', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Hausnummer*'))
           ...
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'address';
    }
}
```

EmployeeForm:

```
class EmployeeForm extends AbstractType
{
    // set the data class of the form
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'KuMiV\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Titel', 'required' => false))
            ->add('firstName', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Vorname*'))
            ->add('lastName', 'text', array(
            ...
            ->add('address', new AddressForm())   
            ...
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Speichern', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success')))
            ->getForm();
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'employee';
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('EmployeeBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function newItemAction(Request $request)
    {
        $employee   = new Employee();
        $form       = $this->createForm(new EmployeeForm(), $employee);
        $form->handleRequest($request);    

        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            // save if submitted
            if ($form->isSubmitted()) 
            {
                $doctrineManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $doctrineManager->persist($employee);
                $doctrineManager->flush();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('EmployeeBundle:Form:newItem.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I think it has something to do with the `"employee" = "Employee"` in `@ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "KuMiV\StoreBundle\Entity\Person", "employee" = "Employee"})`
Because this is the string at the end of the doctrine insert, that I don't defined in my form (neither in $employee after submitting form).

Comment: There are 12 parameters in the query and 13 values in the parameters listed.

Comment: I know, I will update that "employee" was not inserted via form.

Comment: Well show us the corresponding field in your Entity & how you are populating it.

Comment: @TomToms Which corresponding field in which Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling so hard with this error I finally found the solution. It is so simple.
I defined the doctrine meta data in the wrong class.

Like it's said in the [doctrine reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance): "The @InheritanceType, @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorMap must be specified on the topmost class that is part of the mapped entity hierarchy."

(I defined it in the inherited class)

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your Person class, the address field is referenced to "Adress" which is not exists as it's name is Address.

It it mistyped in your code as well?

Comment: Sorry was an older code snippet, I renamed it. It is not mistyped in my code.